# CSS padding an image sprite

Tags: html, css

[image: social media icons]

I have this image that I am using for sprites with CSS.
Here is my html and css code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>
  .socialLink li.fb {
    background: url(socialIconSet.png) no-repeat -44px -5px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 24px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .socialLink li.tw {
    background: url(socialIconSet.png) no-repeat -82px -7px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 21px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
  .socialLink li.ig {
    background: url(socialIconSet.png) no-repeat -7px -5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    padding-left: 30px;
  }
</style>

<html>
  <body>
    <ul class="hf4 socialLink col">
      <li class="fb"><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>

      <li class="tw"><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>

      <li class="ig"><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

The padding is using extra parts of the image, is there a way to add padding without including more of the image?

Comment: You could put the social icons into a `span` that you put inside of the `li`.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your LI items a ***flex*** row and place your icon inside a `span` tag before the `a` tag. Then all you have to do is add `display:flex` to your ***li*** elements, a `margin-left` to your *child* ***a*** elements and add the `span` tag to the css that styles the individual icons `socialLink li.fb` => `.socialLink li span.fb`. Then you can control the space between the **span** tag and the **a** tag using the a tags `left-margin`.

Also an optional rule with ***flex*** is to add a **[gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap)** in the parent element to add space between the child elements.

```
.socialLink li {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}
```

If this is not what you were looking to do, please let me know and I can adjust my answer or remove it.

```css
.socialLink li {
  display: flex;
  /* also an optional rule with flex is to add a gap in the parent element
     to add space between the child elements within the flex parent element
     
     gap: 1rem; */
}

.socialLink li a {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.socialLink li span.fb {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMehn.png) no-repeat -44px -5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 24px;
}

.socialLink li span.tw {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMehn.png) no-repeat -82px -7px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 21px;
}

.socialLink li span.ig {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMehn.png) no-repeat -7px -5px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hf4 socialLink col">
  <li><span class="fb"></span><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>

  <li><span class="tw"></span><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>

  <li><span class="ig"></span><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
</ul>
```